# Average in Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a large data set, 730 values all in a single column (i.e. 730 rows). I want to split the data into groups of 24, except for the last group which will only have 10 values (since 730 is not divisible by 24).

I want to find the average of each set of 24 values, is there an easy way to do this in Matlab?

Comment: a moving average? every possible combination of 24? or discrete sets (e.g. 730/24)?

Comment: What do you mean by "every 24 set of values"? Could you be more specific about what you are trying to do? Do you want to split the list into groups of 24 and then average each group?

Comment: I think he is trying to get the avg for each 24 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Given a vector `x`, for example:

```
>> x = [11 4 3 3 4 22 4 5 32 3 53 23 5 4 6 4 452 ]';
```

And some batch size (24 in your case, 5 for this toy example)

```
>> batchSize = 5;
```

Start by preallocating a matrix of NaNs.  (This makes handling the odd size case at the end easier)

```
>> preAverage = nan(batchSize,ceil(length(x)/batchSize))
preAverage =
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Then place your values from `x` into the new matrix.  (This is set up to use the column-first indexing)

```
>> preAverage(1:length(x)) = x;
preAverage =
    11    22    53     4
     4     4    23   452
     3     5     5   NaN
     3    32     4   NaN
     4     3     6   NaN
```

Then use `nanmean` to take the average, ignoring `NaN` values;

```
>> batchedAvgValues = nanmean(preAverage)
batchedAvgValues =
        5         13.2         18.2          228
```

Comment: WOW....works perfect!!! Thank you so much...I was trying to find the average in Excel and it was so tedious...this makes things easier....thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a moving average of every 24 rows you should use filter:

```
y = filter(ones(24,1), 24, x)
```

or

```
y = filter(ones(24,1)./24, 1, x)
```

Comment: I wanted to split the data into groups of 24 and then find the average of each group, (however since 730 is not divisible by 24 the last group will have just nine values). Can this be done in Matlab ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Matlab has a built in mean function that can take the average of your column.

You can select different parts of a column using array splicing notation.

For example, if your column is named xs:

```
mean(xs(1:24))
```

will get the mean (average) of the first 24 values of xs.

Comment: ^ I tried that function...but I wanted to find the mean of every 24 set of values, like 1-24, 25-48 and so on, which totals to 31 set of mean values. Is there a function that can be used to get the mean of all the 31 set at a time ?? (hope it makes sense!!)